# Adding movie recording to AVCamFilter doesn't work on iPad

Tags: swift, avfoundation, metal, avcapturesession, mtkview

I’m working with Apple’s [AVCamFilter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/additional_data_capture/avcamfilter_applying_filters_to_a_capture_stream) demo app. Unfortunately it doesn’t include movie recording capability, so I tried creating a movie output, right below the photo output, at the top of the class:

```
let movieOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
```

I then added the output (again, right below where the photo output is added) in `configureSession()` like so:

```
if session.canAddOutput(movieOutput) {
        session.addOutput(movieOutput)
    } else {
        print("Could not add movie output to the session")
        setupResult = .configurationFailed
        session.commitConfiguration()
        return
    }
```

On my iPhone (13 Pro), this works and I can succesfully record video. But on my iPad Air the camera preview just goes black. No error comes up, and `setupResult` prints as "success", but there's no video. Interestingly, if I take a photo with the shutter button, it successfully captures (with an image) to the photo library.

I've made no other modifications to the project, so you can try this yourself by downloading the demo app and just adding those lines.

Update: I've found some related posts about how `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` may be incompatible with `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`. But if that's true why does it work on my iPhone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never figured out why it worked on my iPhone, but as a workaround I implemented AVAssetWriter. This should allow AVCamFilter to record video (and audio!) on any device.

First, add `AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` to the class declaration.

Add these variables to the class:

```
let audioSession = AVCaptureSession()
private let audioDataOutputQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "AudioDataQueue", qos: .userInitiated, attributes: [], autoreleaseFrequency: .workItem)
private let audioDataOutput = AVCaptureAudioDataOutput()

private var _assetWriter: AVAssetWriter?
private var _assetWriterVideoInput: AVAssetWriterInput?
private var _assetWriterAudioInput: AVAssetWriterInput?
private var _adpater: AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor?
private var _filename = ""
private var _time: Double = 0
private var _captureState = _CaptureState.idle

private enum _CaptureState {
    case idle, start, capturing, end
}
```

I put the audio on a seperate session becuase I wanted to include haptics (see note below), but you can put them on the same session if you wish.

In `configureSession()`, after the final `session.commitConfiguration()`, add:

```
audioSession.beginConfiguration()

// Add an audio input
let audioDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .audio)
let audioInput = try! AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: audioDevice!)
if audioSession.canAddInput(audioInput) {
    audioSession.addInput(audioInput)
}

// Add an audio data output
if audioSession.canAddOutput(audioDataOutput) {
    audioSession.addOutput(audioDataOutput)
    audioDataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: audioDataOutputQueue)
} else {
    print("Could not add audio data output to the session")
}

audioSession.commitConfiguration()
```

Then replace the contents of `captureOutput(_ didOutput from:)` with this:

```
if connection.output == videoDataOutput {
            processVideo(sampleBuffer: sampleBuffer)
        }
        
        let timestamp = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer).seconds

            switch _captureState {
            case .start:
                // Set up recorder
                guard connection.output == videoDataOutput else { break } // ensures that the writer is set up with a video frame. When it starts with audio, it can fail.
                _filename = UUID().uuidString
                let videoPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("\(_filename).mov")
                let writer = try! AVAssetWriter(outputURL: videoPath, fileType: .mov)
                let settings = videoDataOutput.recommendedVideoSettingsForAssetWriter(writingTo: .mov)
                let input = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: .video, outputSettings: settings) // [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.h264, AVVideoWidthKey: 1920, AVVideoHeightKey: 1080])
                input.mediaTimeScale = CMTimeScale(bitPattern: 600)
                input.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true
                input.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi/2)
                let adapter = AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor(assetWriterInput: input, sourcePixelBufferAttributes: nil)
                if writer.canAdd(input) {
                    writer.add(input)
                }
                let audioSettings = audioDataOutput.recommendedAudioSettingsForAssetWriter(writingTo: .mov)
                let audioInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: .audio, outputSettings: audioSettings)
                audioInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true
                if writer.canAdd(audioInput) {
                    writer.add(audioInput)
                }
                writer.startWriting()
                writer.startSession(atSourceTime: .zero)
                _assetWriter = writer
                _assetWriterVideoInput = input
                _assetWriterAudioInput = audioInput
                _adpater = adapter
                _captureState = .capturing
                _time = timestamp
            case .capturing:
                if connection.output == videoDataOutput {
                        // Process video frames and write to videoInput
                    if _assetWriterVideoInput?.isReadyForMoreMediaData == true {
                        let time = CMTime(seconds: timestamp - _time, preferredTimescale: CMTimeScale(600))
                        _adpater?.append(previewView.pixelBuffer!, withPresentationTime: time)
                    }
                } else if connection.output == audioDataOutput {
                    // Process audio samples and write to audioInput
                    if _assetWriterAudioInput!.isReadyForMoreMediaData {
                        let time = CMTime(seconds: timestamp - _time, preferredTimescale: CMTimeScale(600))
                        if let modifiedBuffer = setPresentationTimestamp(sampleBuffer: sampleBuffer, presentationTimestamp: time) {
                            _assetWriterAudioInput!.append(modifiedBuffer)
                        }
                    }
                }
                break
            case .end:
                guard _assetWriterVideoInput?.isReadyForMoreMediaData == true, _assetWriter!.status != .failed else { break }
                let url = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("\(_filename).mov")
                _assetWriterVideoInput?.markAsFinished()
                _assetWriterAudioInput?.markAsFinished()
                _assetWriter?.finishWriting { [weak self] in
                    self?._captureState = .idle
                    self?._assetWriter = nil
                    self?._assetWriterVideoInput = nil
                    self?._assetWriterAudioInput = nil
                  UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(url.path, nil, nil, nil)
                }
            default:
                break
            }
```

(You can do whatever you want with the URL, it’s saved to the photo library here as an example)

Lastly you’ll need this to sync the audio and video:

```
func setPresentationTimestamp(sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, presentationTimestamp: CMTime) -> CMSampleBuffer? {
        var sampleBufferCopy: CMSampleBuffer? = nil
        var timingInfoArray = [CMSampleTimingInfo(duration: CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: 30), presentationTimeStamp: presentationTimestamp, decodeTimeStamp: CMTime.invalid)]

        var status = CMSampleBufferCreateCopyWithNewTiming(allocator: kCFAllocatorDefault, sampleBuffer: sampleBuffer, sampleTimingEntryCount: 1, sampleTimingArray: &timingInfoArray, sampleBufferOut: &sampleBufferCopy)

        if status == noErr {
            return sampleBufferCopy
        } else {
            // Handle the error
            return nil
        }
    }
```

To actually trigger the video recording, change `_captureState` to `.start`, and change it to `.end` to finish.

Notes:

-You may see black frames at the start and end of videos. I tried a variety of approaches to solve this but none worked, so I changed `writer.startSession(atSourceTime: .zero)` to `writer.startSession(atSourceTime: CMTime(seconds: 0.25, preferredTimescale: CMTimeScale(600)))` , which simply trims 0.25 seconds off the start. For the end, right before `_assetWriterVideoInput?.markAsFinished()`, adding this seems to fix it:

```
let endTime = timestamp - _time
_assetWriter?.endSession(atSourceTime: CMTime(seconds: endTime, preferredTimescale: CMTimeScale(600)))
```

-Running the mic disables haptics. This is why I used a seperate audio session: so that I can tell the session to startRunning when the video recording starts, and stopRunning when it ends. As long as it's not recording, you should be able to use haptics. Note that you will of course have to get audio permissions before audio recording will work.

-Credit to here for some of the AVAssetWriter code: https://gist.github.com/yusuke024/b5cd3909d9d7f9e919291491f6b381f0

-I’m by no means an expert! So anyone feel free to point out if something here is unnecessary/wrong.